# Using a JSON file instead of a database - feasible?

Tags: json, database-design, github, metadata, collaboration

Imagine I've created a new javascript framework, and want to showcase some examples that utilise it, and let other people add examples if they want. Crucially I want this to all be on github.

I imagine I would need to provide a template HTML document which includes the framework, and sorts out all the header and footer correctly. People would then add examples into the examples folder.

However, doing it this way, I would just end up with a long list of HTML files. What would I need to do if I wanted to add some sort of metadata about each example, like tags/author/date etc, which I could then provide search functionality on? If it was just me working on this, I think I would probably set up a database. But because it's a collaboration, this is a bit tricky.

Would it work if each HTML file had a corresponding entry in a JSON file listing all the examples where I could put this metadata? Would I be able to create some basic search functionality using this? Would it be a case of: Step 1 : create new example file, step 2: add reference to file and file metadata to JSON file?

A good example of something similar to what I want is wbond's package manager http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community

(There is not going to be a lot of create/update/destroy going on - mainly just reading.

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/lowdb

Answer (score 5):

Check out this Javascript database: http://www.taffydb.com/

There are other Javascript databases that let you load JSON data and then do database operations. Taffy lets you search for documents.

It sounds like a good idea to me though - making HTML files and an associated JSON document that has meta data about it.